# Trying to create a simple time picker with a calendar written in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery, but managed to build a calendar that is updated for 2020 and changes colors when clicking on each number. The last piece to this is to add time slots to each day of the week, so you can click on a time to make an appointment. Is there an easy way to make this happen with only using jQuery, html, and css? It's for a school project, so it only has to be client side. I have little knowledge about server side languages.

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  function generateCalendar(d) {
    function monthDays(month, year) {
      var result = [];
      var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
        result.push(i);
      }
      return result;
    }
    Date.prototype.monthDays = function() {
      var d = new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth() + 1, 0);
      return d.getDate();
    };
    var details = {
      // totalDays: monthDays(d.getMonth(), d.getFullYear()),
      totalDays: d.monthDays(),
      weekDays: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
      months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    };
    var start = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth()).getDay();
    var cal = [];
    var day = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      cal.push(['<tr>']);
      for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (i === 0) {
          cal[i].push('<td>' + details.weekDays[j] + '</td>');
        } else if (day > details.totalDays) {
          cal[i].push('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
        } else {
          if (i === 1 && j < start) {
            cal[i].push('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
          } else {
            cal[i].push('<td class="day">' + day++ + '</td>');
          }
        }
      }
      cal[i].push('</tr>');
    }
    cal = cal.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    }, []).join('');
    $('table').append(cal);
    $('#month').text(details.months[d.getMonth()]);
    $('#year').text(d.getFullYear());
    $('td.day').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).addClass('hover');
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  }
  $('#left').click(function() {
    $('table').text('');
    if (currentDate.getMonth() === 0) {
      currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 1, 11);
      generateCalendar(currentDate);
    } else {
      currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() - 1)
      generateCalendar(currentDate);
    }
  });
  $('#right').click(function() {
    $('table').html('<tr></tr>');
    if (currentDate.getMonth() === 11) {
      currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0);
      generateCalendar(currentDate);
    } else {
      currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1)
      generateCalendar(currentDate);
    }
  });
  generateCalendar(currentDate);
});
```

```css
/*  The follow code is a "reset" of sorts. The box-sizing property can make
    building CSS layouts easier and a lot more intuitive.
*/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Styling and layout below */
h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

td, #year {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 22px;
}
td, #month {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 22px;
}

.hover {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

.dropdown-menu {
  font-family: "proxima-nova",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: #081826;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: -90px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 50px;
}

.dropdown-container {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-item{
color: #ffffff;
}

.ek-nav {
  background-color: #081826;
}

.fa-arrow-left {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

a .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Lato";
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-link i {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li .nav-item {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: normal;
}

li .profile {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Jeff Health Pal</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap, Font Awesome, Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/goa8mly.css">

</head>
  <body>

    <!-- This is the start of the wrapper div -->

    <div class="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <header id="top">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark ek-nav">
        <button type="button" class="btn arrow-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Schedule</a>

        <div class="dropdown-container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown-menu" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-sm-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <i class="fas fa-user profile"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <h1>Erin King</h1>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-directions"></i>Directions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i>Inbox</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far fa-bell"></i>Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i>Settings</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
  </header>

<!--Calendar-->
<div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center"><a id="left" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"> </i></a><span>&nbsp;</span><span id="month"> </span><span>&nbsp;</span><span id="year"> </span><span>&nbsp;</span>
          <a id="right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <table class="table"></table>
        </div>
    </div>



      <!-- Footer of the page -->


    </div>

    <!-- Scripts go below this line. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand meaning of "time slots" can you explain it please?

Comment: For each day of the week, I need appointment time slots. So, when you click the day you want on the calendar, times will show up, so you can pick an appointment time.